# Can it be shown in experiment that the momentum (or position) states of the electron and proton in hydrogen are entangled?

Tags: momentum, quantum-entanglement, measurements, superposition, observables

The states of the electron and proton in hydrogen are entangled. Which means that the momentum and position of both are entangled. Can this be shown in an experiment, so if you measure the momentum (or a small range of them) of the proton you will know in advance what the momentum of the electron will be?
If you first have to separate them, to do a measurement on them, will the information of the entanglement show itself in the measurement? As the information of entanglement of two spin states can show itself in measurement?

Comment: From conservation of energy and momentum, once the masses are know, knowing/measuring  the fpur vector of one particle , the four vector of the other is known.

Comment: _"the momentum and position of both are entangled"_ — do you mean momentum is entangled with position? This can't be right, because these observables are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

In a two body bound state, (quantum mechanical or not) from conservation of energy and momentum, once the masses are known, measuring  the [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) of one particle , the four vector of the other is known.

Comment: To clarify: This assumes that the atom has a single well-defined total momentum. But if the atom is localized to within $\Delta x$ (which is always finite in the real world), then the atom must be in a superposition of different total-momentum eigenstates with spread $\Delta p\sim\hbar/\Delta x$, so knowing one constituents' momentum typically only reveals the other's momentum to the accuracy $\sim \Delta p$, even if the measurement is much more precise than $\Delta p$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the states of the electron and the proton in a hydrogen atom are entangled. The wave function of a hydrigen atom has form
$$
\psi(\mathbf{x}_e, \mathbf{x}_p) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{R}}\phi(\mathbf{x}_e- \mathbf{x}_p),
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{R}=\frac{m_e\mathbf{x}_e+ m_p\mathbf{x}_p}{m_e+m_p}
$$
is the position of the center-of-mass of the atom, whereas $\phi(\mathbf{x}_e- \mathbf{x}_p)$ is one of the hydrogen eigenfunctions discussed in any quantum mechanics text. Function $\psi(\mathbf{x}_e, \mathbf{x}_p)$ can be expanded in terms of momentum eigenstates of electron and proton
$$
\psi(\mathbf{x}_e, \mathbf{x}_p) = \int d^3\mathbf{k}_e \int d^3\mathbf{k}_pe^{i\mathbf{k}_e\mathbf{x}_e}e^{i\mathbf{k}_p\mathbf{x}_p} \varphi(\mathbf{k}_e, \mathbf{k}_p),
$$
which is an entangled state. We could further calculation the coefficients $\varphi(\mathbf{k}_e, \mathbf{k}_p)$ using the form of the wave function given above as:
$$
\varphi(\mathbf{k}_e, \mathbf{k}_p) = \int d^3\mathbf{x}_e \int d^3\mathbf{x}_pe^{-i\mathbf{k}_e\mathbf{x}_e}e^{-i\mathbf{k}_p\mathbf{x}_p}\psi(\mathbf{x}_e, \mathbf{x}_p) =\\
\int d^3\mathbf{q}\tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{q}) \delta^3\left(\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{k}\frac{m_e}{m_e+m_p}-\mathbf{k}_e\right)
\delta^3\left(\mathbf{q}-\mathbf{k}\frac{m_p}{m_e+m_p}-\mathbf{k}_p\right)=\\
\delta^3\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_e-\mathbf{k}_p\right)
\tilde{\phi}\left(\frac{m_p\mathbf{k}_e + m_e\mathbf{k}_p}{m_e+m_p}\right),
$$
where $\tilde(\mathbf{q})$ is the Fourier transform of $\phi(\mathbf{x})$.

Separating the proton and the electron would mean changing the state by ionizing the atom - whether the two will remain entangled depends on the process of separation. Measuring a momentum of one of the two particles is hard due to their strong binding, but this probably could be done in accelerator experiments. We then see from the equation above that the momentum state of one particle is related to the momentum state of the other - if we do manage to measure the momentum of the electron, we woudl obtain the momentum of proton as $\mathbf{k}_p=\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_e$. It could be much easier to emasure their angular momenta.

Comment: what about conservation of momentum!!!! If there are only two particles involved....

Comment: @annav I think it is impossible to discuss without actually specifying  the measurement process: how do we break a hydrogen atom while conserving its momentum?

Comment: a photon with just the the energy of ionisation? it will be three fourvectors, but the energy is the same for the level and the photon?

Comment: @annav I think the problem here is that initially neither the electron, nor the proton are in momentum eigenstates. So measuring one in a momentum eigenstates destroys the entanglement - at least partially. It could be different, if we measure the angular momenta instead.

Comment: It does destroy it, but it gives a handle to the other particles four vector. The same when measuring spin one for a photon from a pi0 decay one knows because of QM entanglement the other has spin -1

Comment: @annav I ahve clarified my answer.

Comment: This is fine, leaves the door open:)